# Adding providers to Sitefinity content modules (News, Images,...)

Tags: sitefinity

Anyone familiar with adding providers to content modules?

I have two Sitefinity sites that I want to share the news content items of, one with the other. So when I add news content and images to one, I want to show the full content items in the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sitefinity does offer their [multisite management](http://www.sitefinity.com/product/multisite-management) module but it looks like its only available for [certain editions](http://www.sitefinity.com/purchase) as a $5000 add on. Not sure what the budget is but maybe that's worth it since it allows the sharing of content between sites.

If not what we had proposed as a potential solution for this to a client was to have one site be the entry point for news items and just run the news lists and details pages off the built in widget templates. Then on the other site we wanted to share the content with, create a custom .ascx or Sitefinity mvc widget to pull the news items from the other site using the built in web services on that site. You'd probably have to write a couple controls for it, one to get the list and one to pull the details but its a poor man's way to get shared content without writing a custom content provider or paying for multisite.

Here's some documentation on using the web services:

http://www.sitefinity.com/blogs/svetlayankova/posts/svetla-yankovas-blog/2011/11/01/getting_started_with_restful_services_in_sitefinity

http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/developers-guide/deep-dive/client-side-programming